# python interpreter segmentation fault at cmp instruction in docker

Tags: python, docker, segmentation-fault

I was running a python script in a docker environment, after running it several hours, I got a segmentation fault and core dump on python3. I used gdb to analyze the core, it seems the last frame of the core dump is at `__GI___select select.c:41`. Other frames are just `??()` and `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault()` .

I try to disassemble the last frame, it shows the crash happened on `=> 0x00007ff212080ff7 <+23>:    cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax`, which tries to compare the select syscall return value with -4096 to determine if they should move the negative part to errno. This instruction should not cause any segfault since there's no memory access.

The value of $rax is `-514 (ERESTARTNOHAND)`, which seems very wield.

According to the log, the corruption seems happend on my try block of `subprocess.run(arg_test, timeout=5)`

I originally thought it caused by limited stack size, but I face the same problem after setting stack ulimit to 262144 kb

Could anyone tells me how I suppose to debug this kind of problem? thank you so much

-------------------- edit ------------------------

The crash location seems random, I found another crash at `=> 0x00007f50813c31cc <+108>:   cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax` of `__GI___sigtimedwait`, and the value of `$rax` is `-11`.

I don't understand how could this instruction cause segmentation fault.